# AZURE Boards - Priority Changing Does not Change Board Order of PBI's

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have recently started using AZURE Devops boards. I have set up a board based on 'Agile' process. Below is the picture, how my board looks at the moment

[image: Bee Azure Board]

The problem I am facing at moment is, if I change the priority of Backlog Item 2 to 1, the board on refresh does not re-order the column based on new priority of the PBI's.

If I do the same action in the backlog also, it does not re-order backlog based on a new priority.

Looking forward for the advice, what Am I doing wrong here.

Thanks,
Bee

Comment: Hi friend, not getting latest information about this issue. Please feel free to let me know if my answer helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking forward for the advice, what Am I doing wrong here.

1.It's expected behavior cause the `Backlog` doesn't reorder automatically based on `Priority`.

Please check [Reorder your backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/create-your-backlog?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#reorder-your-backlog), the reorder option of Backlogs is a **drag-and-drop reorder feature**. We can only reorder the Items via `drag-and-drop`, the order won't be automatically reordered based on changes in priority.

Meanwhile, the order in Boards will be reordered when you reorder the backlog with this option enabled:

[image]

If you've enabled this option in Boards settings, the order in Boards will be reordered automatically once the order in Backlogs has changes. But both orders in Boards and Backlogs won't be affected by changes of Priority, it's by design. (You may have seen the blog shared by **Matt** above)

2.Though we don't support sorting the Items based on Priority, [Define style rules to highlight high-priority cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops#define-style-rules-to-highlight-cards) can also make some help.

[image]

[image]

You can't reorder them automatically in Boards tab based on Priority, but you can have a style rule to highlight high-priority items automatically in Boards. Not perfect, but it can make some help for you to find those high-priority items easily. (BTW, if you do want a new feature to reorder Items automatically based on Priority, feel free to post a feature request in Our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html))

Comment: thanks for sharing a perfect explanation. I understand but don't you think, re-ordering on based on priority is a key feature that any tool should have. For example, Atlassian JIRA has this feature. What is the driver behind, not to have this feature?

Comment: Agree, i also think that'll be a good feature. Sorry but I'm not sure about the reason why this feature is not supported yet, but you can feel free to share the feedback in the User Voice forum. The team would consider it if it gets enough votes!

Comment: thanks Lance, i am also gonna post another question on StackOverflow, regarding power automate integration with azure DevOps boards. Will be worth for you to have a look. Also i am gonna post in user forum for this feature. BTW i love how we can add tasks in Azure Devops only from the board directly :), pretty cool and handy.

Comment: I have posted the relevant question, will be keen to get your feedback. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907396/power-automate-integration-with-azure-devops-boards-create-a-new-issue-with-pa

Comment: Apologies to bring to your attention, here is another question, I am facing an issue with, if you feel appropriate, can you have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925934/power-automate-azure-devops-integration-work-item-getting-created-in-project

Comment: I'll check that if I have time :) And normally, if you create an issue with azure-devops tag, our engineers would view it and help if we have any idea just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62908499/10910450). Have a nice day~

Comment: Thank so much @Lance Li-MSFT. Though i have figured out a solution myself for it. Will keep an eye on what others can help with.

Answer (score 1):

Priority is just the relative importance you've defined for that item in the backlog.  The actual order that you would want to complete items in the backlog orders by the [stack rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863642/what-does-stack-rank-mean#:%7E:text=It%20assigns%20a%20priority%20to%20a%20requirement.&text=Stack%20Rank%20is%20not%20priority,an%20earlier%2Flower%20rank..).

The backlog priority (stack rank) number can be confusing. The numbers are very large because of performance reasons that they added if they tried to renumber the priority on everything.  There was a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field/) a long time ago that covered their thinking on that field.