# Power Automate Integration with Azure DevOps Boards - Create a new Issue with Parent link

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I am trying to integrate Power Automate with Azure DevOps boards. I want to create a new work-item in my backlog, when a new email arrives, containing a particular subject. I have achieved, it using existing templates.

Now the problem I am facing is, when this backlog item is created, I want to add a parent feature link to this backlog item automatically via power automate.

I have done a bit of R&D, and I could not see, this as achievable through Power Automate. Can anyone please help with it?

Thanks,
bee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when this backlog item is created, I want to add a parent feature link to this backlog item automatically via power automate.

At the **Create work item step**, you could add the link type and link URL parameters.

`Link type: Hierarchy-reverse`

`Link URL: https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{ProjectName}/_workitems/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work item ID}`

For example:

[image]

Then the new issue work item will be added with parent work item.

[image]

Comment: hey @Kevin Lu-MSFT I used the method you suggested. I am giving the full Link URL also like this, https://dev.azure.com/BeenishZaidi0727/Automate%20Project/_backlogs/backlog/Automate%20Project%20Team/Features/?workitem=116 , but the flow fails stating.Linking to a work item requires the full url.

Comment: hello @benz. Could you please use this url: `https://dev.azure.com/BeenishZaidi0727/Automate%20Project/_workitems/_apis/wit/workItems/116`? Then you could check if it could work.

Comment: Thank you so much kevin, it worked like magic. I also checked the API documentation, it does say, we need to use visual studio API link format :). Thank you so much. @Kevin Lu-MSFT, is it possible that, we can also add attachment received via email to work item types?