# Power Automate - Azure DevOps Integration - Work Item Getting Created In Project Backlog and Area Path Backlog

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I am using power automate for Azure DevOps integration. Here is what I want to achieve. I want to create a new work item when an email arrives in a project but in a specific Area Path for the team.

I am providing Area Path and Iteration Path in my flow configuration, but when the flow triggers, it creates work item both in Project Backlog and Area Path backlog, where as I only want it to create the issue in the specific Area Path.

Can someone kindly help? Thanks, Bee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, here is how I resolved this duplication issue.

- Provide all the necessary configuration in your workflow.
- Include your area-path in the workflow
- Provide a unique parent-id you want to link your work-item. Feature or an EPIC.

Seen the screenshot below.

[image: Feature Link]

After I provide a unique parent/child relationship, it stopped creating duplicate backlog items in my Project backlog and area path backlog.

Hope this helps everyone.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)